# How do I convert a list of strings to a proper sentence

Tags: python, arrays, string

How do I convert a list of strings to a proper sentence like this?

```
lst = ['eat', 'drink', 'dance', 'sleep'] 
string = 'I love"
output: "I love to eat, drink, dance and sleep."
```

Note: the "to" needs to be generated and not added manually to string
Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a programming assignment. At which part are you stuck? Do you know about list slices, which you'll probably need for this (separating the list into first and last element, and everything in-between)?

Comment: Is this an NLP question? Is this a question to do with the join() method? What does 'needs to be generated' mean? What have you tried?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what you do ask ? Do you want to generate the "and" at the end ? If we add more verbs, how the output is supposed to change, ect
(and more importantly why the "to" musn't be added "manually", but "I love" seems ok)

Comment: I guess, if **to** needs to be generated then *I love* should be fed to a some trained AI model which would then easily guess and pick respective verb, to add to given list of strings. just like google search does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, using list to string joining:

```py
lst = ['eat', 'drink', 'dance', 'sleep'] 
string = 'I love'
output = string + ' to ' + ', '.join(lst)
output = re.sub(r', (?!.*,)', ' and ', output)
print(output)  # I love to eat, drink, dance and sleep
```

Note that the call to `re.sub` above selectively replaces the final comma with `and`.

Answer (score 3):

You can join all the verbs except the last with commas, and add the last with an `and`

```
def build(start, verbs):
    return f"{start} to {', '.join(verbs[:-1])} and {verbs[-1]}."

string = 'I love'
lst = ['eat', 'drink', 'dance', 'sleep']
print(build(string, lst))  # I love to eat, drink, dance and sleep

lst = ['eat', 'drink', 'dance', 'sleep', 'run', 'walk', 'count']
print(build(string, lst))  # I love to eat, drink, dance, sleep, run, walk and count.
```

Answer (score 2):

Heyy, you can add string elements of lists to form bigger string by doing the following :-

```
verbs = lst[:-1].join(", ") # This will result in "eat, drink, dance"
verbs = verbs + " and " + lst[-1] # This will result in "eat, drink, dance and sleep"
string = string + ' to ' + verbs # This will result in "I love to eat, drink, dance and sleep"
print(string)
```